# Javascript special escaping characters

Tags: javascript, html-escape-characters

Hi I am using JavaScript function that is called from an anchor link which passes a title that has a special character could you please tell me how can I escape the single quote in the string passed to the function.

The sample string is given below,

```
string desc="test's/test2'w";
```

sample link html

```
"<a href="javascript:getdata(\'' + desc+ '\',);void(0);">TEST</a>"
```

so the function `getdata` is not called since it's not escaping that character.

Its a legacy system I will need to work with HTML only

Comment: I'm assuming that the Html is in a javascript string ?

Comment: no its an anchor link with a js function call on href action

Answer (score 4):

Don't generate HTML by smashing together strings, use DOM. Don't use JavaScript URIs, use event handlers.

```
var desc = "test's/test2'w";
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.appendChild( document.createTextNode('TEST') );
link.href = "fallback.html";
link.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    getData(desc);
    evt.preventDefault();
});
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone who's against tangling html in js.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the names of all the *HTML* entities, you can still *HTML* encode them

```
function htmlEncode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\da-z()\[\] .,\/\\]/g, function (m) {
        return '&#' + m.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
}
htmlEncode("test's/test2'w"); // "test&#39;s/test2&#39;w"
```

Where `\da-z()\[\] .,\/\\` is the white list of permitted characters.

If you want to generate HTML as *Strings*, this is okay, but if you want to make new *DOM* elements, [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677487/1615483) is much better in the long run.